# Trying to capture API response code from gspread_dataframe function

Tags: python, gspread

I have a short loop updating several gsheets, and I'd like to capture the return code from the requests to the API. I'm using the `gspread` and `gspread_dataframe` libraries. I know the function that I need to capture the response for is the `set_as_dataframe()` function, but I'm unable to find anything in the documentation about how to return the response code.

```py
import os      
import time           
import gspread 
import gspread_dataframe as gd
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

os.chdir('C:\\mydir')  # locate ourselves in the directory
# import tbls to push to gsheet
import pull_tbls
# example dataframes 
tbl_1 = {'first_col':  [1,2,3],
        'second_col': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']}
tbl_2 = {'first_col':  [4,5,6],
        'second_col': ['potato', 'carrot', 'lemon']}

tbl_1 = pull_tbls.tbl_1
tbl_2 = pull_tbls.tbl_2

# set scope 
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

# provide credentials 
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my_json_keyfile.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
# list of the google sheets we want to update

sheet_list = ['tbl_1', 'tbl_2']

# loop 
for sheet in sheet_list:
    print(sheet)
    sheet = gc.open(sheet)
    # sleep to avoid API limits 
    time.sleep(60)
    wks   = sheet.sheet1
    # delete existing rows 
    wks.clear()
    # when sheet matches tbl name
    # replace sheet contents with tbl 
    sheet_name = wks.spreadsheet.title
    
    if sheet_name == 'tbl_1':
        new_data = tbl_1
    elif sheet_name == 'tbl_2':
        new_data = tbl_2
    else:
        print('sheet name not found!')        
    # update gsheet with new data  
    if new_data.empty:
        print(sheet_name + ' is empty!')
        continue
    gd.set_with_dataframe(wks, new_data) #this is the API response I want to capture
    # sleep to avoid API limits
    time.sleep(100)
```

I'm not sure where in this process I'm able to capture the API response to updating the gsheet.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `capture the API response to updating the gsheet`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, what is `pull_tbls`?

Comment: From what I see you have 2 options. The slow option: you open an issue in the project `gspread-dataframe` and request that it would be useful if the function `set_with_dataframe` returns the sheet API result. The short option: you add a new `handler` on the logger option to catch the text produced by the logger object and parse it. See [handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handler-basic)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening an [issue](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe/issues/48) with the maintainer. For anyone looking to see the API response for their `gspread_dataframe()` calls, if you add a logger and include `logging.getLogger('gspread_dataframe')` in your logger configuration, you should be able to see the results.